# User directory folder exists but is missing

Tags: windows, directory

When I try to find the C:\users\user directory I cannot see it's icon from the users directory, however I am able to navigate to it using the pathname above on windows explorer or cmd how can I get the icon back to it's correct place?

Thanks,

Gracias,

Comment: Did you turn on "show hidden files and folders" in the Explorer options? Unless the account you're working from has access rights to that folder, it shouldn't be visible by default, yet you can still try to get to it directly via the path box.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see it without switching to "Show hidden files, folders, and drives" type in cmd:

```
attrib -S -H C:\users\user
```

`-S` removes system attribute and `-H` removes hidden attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the option to [show hidden files](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Show-hidden-files)